# Getting nodes/child nodes from html

Tags: javascript, php, html, parent-child, children

The first thing I do is I echo some html code:

```
echo "<div>
        <file>somefile</file>
        <file>another file</file>
      </div>";
```

Then I through JavaScript find all instances of file:

```
var file = document.getElementsByTagName("file");
```

Then I am able to get values from each file by:

```
file[index].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Now I want to add another level to the `<file>` like this:

```
echo "<div>
        <file>
          <em1>element1</em1>
          <em2>element2</em2>
        </file>
      </div>";
```

How can I get those em values? I want to do something like:

```
file[index].getValueFromEm1...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can still access the content of the ems like you did with the original content.

```
var files= document.getElementsByTagName("file");
files[0].childNodes[0].textContent
files[0].childNodes[1].textContent
```

Comment: Interestingly it does work, although I have to use childNodes[1] to get "em1" and childNodes[3] to get "em2", I'll make a few more tests

Comment: I guess it counts amount of tags.

Comment: In some browsers, whitespace can be a childNode as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
file[index].childNodes[0].nodeValue
file[index].childNodes[1].nodeValue
```

etc...

Comment: Error: file[index].childNodes[1] is undefined

Answer (score 0):

try this

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo "<div>
        <file>
          <em1>element1</em1>
          <em2>element2</em2>
        </file>

       <file>
        <em1>element3</em1>
        <em2>element4</em2>
      </file>
      </div>";
?>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
var file = document.getElementsByTagName("file");
for(var i=0; i<file.length; i++)
{
    var filenodes = file[i].childNodes;
    for(var j=0; j<filenodes.length; j++)
    {
        var element_text = filenodes[j].innerHTML;
        if(typeof element_text!= 'undefined')
        {
            alert(element_text);
        }   
    }
}
</script>
```